# change nav links to buttons to look same as same as open up and load an external div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navbar

I have  navbar that looks pretty much and works how i want it, however i want the links to change and/or load new divs to appear on the page or possibly modals. I think the changing to buttons will be easiest way. But ideally i want the buttons to look the same as the links along with the on mouseover colour.

My navbar code is

```
<nav class = 'navbar navbar-default'>
 <div class='container'>
     <div class = 'navbar-header'>
<button type = 'button' class = 'navbar-toggle collapsed' data-toggle = 'collapse' data-target = '#example-navbar-collapse'>
<span class = 'sr-only'>Toggle navigation</span>
<span class='icon-bar top-bar'></span>
<span class='icon-bar middle-bar'></span>
<span class='icon-bar bottom-bar'></span></button>
<a class = 'navbar-brand wow zoomIn' href = '#'><img class='img-responsive2'       
           src='http://www.cheekytransport.co.uk/images/new.png' alt='logo' height='52'></a></div>
<div class = 'collapse navbar-collapse' id = 'example-navbar-collapse'>
    <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-nav'>
        <li class='non-active'><a href='#'>About</a></li>
    </ul>  
    <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-nav'>
        <li class='non-active'><a href='#'>Get bids</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-nav'>
        <li class='non-active'><a href='#'>Register company</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-nav'>
        <li class='non-active'><a href='#'>Help</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-nav'>
        <li class='non-active'><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>
        <li><a href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span> Login</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
 </div>
</nav>
```

The navbar css :

```
 .navbar-default {   
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    border: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    background-color: #00a3fe;
    font-size: 14pt;font-weight: 400;}


.navbar-brand {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right li a {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-nav li a {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    background-color: #49bdfe;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.navbar-toggle, .icon-bar {
    border:1px solid white;
    background-color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean replacing the '' tags with '' tag?
If you did so, just copy the CSS.. You can do it easly this way:

```
.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right li a,
.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right li button {
```

One thing to remember: 
buttons has a little different css attributes, such as 'outline'. Don't forget to relate to those attributes on your css.